# Разрешение геолокации

Tags: ios, objective-c

Всем привет! перед началом использования locationManager выскакивает алерт - разрешить или не разрешать использование данных. так вот, как я могу отследить тот момент когда юзер нажал кнопку и какую (разрешил или нет) и дальше от этого выполнять нужный код

Answer (score 1):

Узнать, что нажал пользователь не получится, но можно узнать имеет ли ваше приложение доступ к определению локации через `[CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled];` либо начать требовать локацию при помощи `-startUpdatingLocation` и если делегат в ответ получит `-locationManager:didFailWithError:`, значит пользователь ответил нет.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать метод `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```